# Serve different resource depending on full URL of requesting page

Tags: html, browser, http-headers

Let's say that we have two pages:

1. `https://www.example.com/first/firstpage.html`
2. `https://www.example.com/second/secondpage.html`

that both load the resource `https://www.example.com/resource.js`

If I want the server that serves `resource.js` to be able to serve a different version of `resource.js` depending on which page the request is coming from, is there a reliable header upon which the full URL of the requesting page can be determined (or maybe there is some other way to determine this)?

I know that there is an `Origin` header, but from my understanding this just represents the domain (and any subdomains) without the full URL and query string. Is there any way for the server to know the full URL and query string that the request for the resource is coming from?

---

If this isn't possible, I know it would be easy to include that info in the JS script tag as follows:

`<script src="/resource.js?origin=/first/firstpage.html"></script>`

But I don't want to have to modify the script tag for each page. Is there some other way to have the page automatically include it's own URL in the query string of the resource request (**without** having to dynamically load the resource using my own JS script - HTML only please!), or just any unique identifier so that the script tag doesn't have to be modified individually on each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the `Referer` header that you can use.

Make sure that your response uses `Vary: Referer`.  Otherwise, browsers are going to cache this resource as if the referring page URL didn't matter.

I'd plead of you not to do this at all though.  You're going to create a rabbit hole of problems, as not all browsers or proxy servers are well behaved.  Some are going to aggressively cache this anyway, no matter what you do with the `Vary` header.

Comment: Good point - I think my original idea may be flawed. As per the second section of my question, is there any way to have the browser automatically append some kind of unique identifier to the URL or some way have the end server that's serving the resource be able to differentiate between a request from `firstpage.html` and `secondpage.html`?

Comment: @abagshaw You would need to either pre-process the HTML you send to the client to contain the URL of what you want to load, or use JavaScript to add the script.